# C# Regex format problem

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following information in a config file:

```
Begin  
0  
0  
13  
44  
59  
047  
8784
```

I'm reading that information and a ton of other information from the config file in as l.

My regex is:

```
string points = points = Regex.Match(l, @"BEGIN\r\n(\d+)$").Groups[1].Value;
```

it's returning `""`

Where am I going wrong with this Regex?

Real solution remove the $:

```
string points = points = Regex.Match(l, @"POINTS\r\n(\d+)").Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the regex? Parse a single line with a number? Validate the whole file layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assuming that your file ends after the first number. To match your first regex, the file would have to look like this:

```
(whatever we want)
BEGIN
0
```

The $ matches the end of your input. Also note the casing on "BEGIN" - if you do not explicitly pass RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, your regex will be case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

The `$` symbol denotes end of line, however you are performing a multi line regex.  I suspect that is why removing the `$` fixes the problem.

Consider passing in the third optional parameter for [RegexOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) and specify `MultiLine`